# How to calculate total value of a column containing mixed currencies

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-finance

Given the following columns, where A is the currency and B is a monetary value in that currency:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 50 |
| USD | 150 |
| EUR | 200 |
| EUR | -150 |
| AUD | 300 |

How can I use the GOOGLEFINANCE function to return the sum the of entire value of column B in another given currency (for example, GBP)?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `=B1*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A1&"GBP")` and drag down. I don't think it would be possible in a neat looking arrayformula to get a direct `SUM()` unless it will probably look terrible. Maybe some script of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

`GOOGLEFINANCE` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA` so you either introduce helper column with dragable formula:

```
=B2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A2&"GBP")
```

[image]

and then sum it:

```
=SUM(D2:D)
```

[image: 0]

or you can construct array:

```
=SUM({
 B2*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A2&"GBP");
 B3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A3&"GBP");
 B4*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A4&"GBP");
 B5*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A5&"GBP");
 B6*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A6&"GBP");
 IF(A7="", 0, B7*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&A7&"GBP"))})
```

[image]