# Google Sheets - sum column with different currencies

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have column A with amount (integer), and column B with currency (USD, GBP, EUR...).

Ideally I want some cell to sum the whole column, converted into USD, taking into account the differenct currencies. I know I can do this by splitting it into different cells and steps (i.e. different cell for each currency etc.), but I was wondering if a formula can be concocted for this.

Also I just learned now about `GOOGLEFINANCE` which is awesome, I'm just not sure how to put it all together.

Edit: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66242493/2996797), I can add a helper column. I was wondering if there's any way not to add one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can try

```
=SUM(MAP(A2:A,B2:B,LAMBDA(val,cur,IFERROR(val*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&cur&"USD"),val))))
```

Comment: I prefer this answer since it automatically adjusts for currencies.